# Compare JSON strings in php

Tags: php, json, string-comparison

I have a countries json file like this

```
[
    {
        "name": "Afghanistan",
        "code": "AF"
    },
    {
        "name": "Åland Islands",
        "code": "AX"
    },
    {
        "name": "Albania",
        "code": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Algeria",
        "code": "DZ"
    },
    {
        "name": "American Samoa",
        "code": "AS"



<?php
    $string = file_get_contents('countries.json');
    $array = json_decode($string, true);

    foreach ($array as $person_name => $person_a) {
        if(strcmp($person_name,'HR')==0)
        {
            echo $person_a['name'].'<br>';
        }
}
?>
```

I need to compare the 'code' to the given value then output the matching country, ow do I find the code for ex. 'GB' then output 'Great Britain'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)<sup>1</sup>:

```
$found = array_search( 'DZ', array_column( $array, 'code' ) );
if( $found === False ) echo "Not Found";
else                   echo $data[$found]['name'];
```

`array_column` returns all 'code' values: with `array_search` you retrieve corresponding key and, if it is found, you can echo corresponding name.

---

<sup>1</sup> available as PHP >= 5.5

Comment: Thank you so much!